# linking from dynamic table cells to specific view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to link from a dynamic table view cell (as part of a search result table) to a specific view controller

The code I have implemented so far is:

SearchViewController.h

```
import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SearchViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *sysTArray;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *filteredsysTArry;
@property IBOutlet UISearchBar *sysTSearchBar;
@end
```

SearchViewController.M

```
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "sysT.h"

@interface SearchViewController ()

@end

@implementation SearchViewController

@synthesize sysTArray;
@synthesize filteredsysTArry;
@synthesize sysTSearchBar;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
// Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

sysTArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                [sysT sysTOfCategory:@"p" name:@"H1"],
                [sysT sysTOfCategory:@"p" name:@"W2"],
                [sysT sysTOfCategory:@"p" name:@"W3"],
                [sysT sysTtOfCategory:@"p" name:@"C4"],
                [sysT sysTOfCategory:@"c" name:@"O5"],
                [sysT sysTOfCategory:@"c" name:@"C6"],
                [sysT sysTOfCategory:@"a" name:@"L7"], nil];

self.filteredSysTArry = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[sysTArray count]];

[self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
return [filteredsysTArry count];
}else{
return [sysTArray count];
}
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}     

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:      (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if ( cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

SysT *sysT = nil;

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
sysT = [filteredsysTArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}else{
sysT = [sysTArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

cell.textLabel.text = sysT.name;
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
return cell;

}





#pragma mark Search Filtering

-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*) searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
[self.filteredSysTArry removeAllObjects];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@",    searchText];
filteredSysTArry = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[sysTArray   filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];

}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller     shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
 [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
return YES;
}

-(BOOL) searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller  shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
[self filterContentForSearchText:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text scope:
 [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]   objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
 return YES;}



@end
```

How do I initiate a specific view controller depending on the data inside the dynamic cell?

To further elaborate, if a user searched H1, and then clicked on that dynamic cell, how would I display the relevant H1 view controller?

As you can probably tell from my very rough code, I'm on a steep learning curve. If you could make your answers as baby proof as possible that would be fantastic, and would really help me out. (Also, I am using storyboards).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: which is called when you select a row. You can get the data for that row by querying your data source, using the indexPath passed into that method. You can then use whatever logic you need to choose which view controller to go to next. You do that by calling performSegueWithIdentifier.

Comment: Thanks for the response rdelmar!

Just to clarify, what did you mean exactly by "querying your data source, using the indexPath passed into that method"?

Apologies if this a stupid question! 
Thanks again for your time

Comment: Using logic very similar to what you wrote in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you can use the selected `indexPath.row` to determine what `sysT` object the selected row represents in from within the  `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` function.

Comment: Thanks oltman and rdelmar for the responses!

I understand everything except for how to use the indexPath.row to determine what sysT object the selected row represents...

Could you please clarify this further for a coding beginner? 

Thanks again!

Comment: @user2019724, you used a line like this: sysT = [sysTArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method -- that's how you got the particular sysT object you wanted out of your array of objects. You do it exactly the same in didSelectRowAtIndexPath (or with the filteredsysTArry array, I'm not sure which one you want).